# Debian: "dpkg -l" name field sometimes includes arch/abi, sometimes not. Why?

Tags: debian, dpkg

(trimmed) `dpkg -l` output on a recent debian bullseye (v11.3) machine:

```
SE  Name              Version             Arch  Description
ii  bind9-host        1:9.16.27-1~deb11u1 amd64 DNS Lookup Utility
ii  bind9-libs:amd64  1:9.16.27-1~deb11u1 amd64 Shared Libraries used by BIND 9
               ^^^^^
```

Question: why does the name field for the bind9-libs package show the architecture/abi whereas the name field for the bind9-host does not show the architecture/abi?

FWIW:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64


$ grep -A6 "Package: bind9-host" /var/lib/dpkg/status
Package: bind9-host
Status: install ok installed
Priority: standard
Section: net
Installed-Size: 376
Maintainer: Debian DNS Team <team+dns@tracker.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64


$ grep -A6 "Package: bind9-libs" /var/lib/dpkg/status
Package: bind9-libs
Status: install ok installed
Priority: standard
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 3734
Maintainer: Debian DNS Team <team+dns@tracker.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
```

Comment: Related: for installed packages, `dpkg -s bind9-libs` would be less error-prone for getting that inormation. Or, if you insist on manually parsing `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, then something like `awk  '/Package: bind9-libs/, /^$/ { print }' /var/lib/dpkg/status` would show correct number of lines, instead of arbirary (and wrong) `grep -A6`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding one more line would reveal the relevant field:

```
$ grep -A7 "Package: bind9-libs" /var/lib/dpkg/status
Package: bind9-libs
Status: install ok installed
Priority: standard
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 3734
Maintainer: Debian DNS Team <team+dns@tracker.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
```

`bind9-libs` is marked “Multi-Arch: same”, which means [it can be co-installed for multiple architectures](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec#Binary_package_control_fields) (*e.g.* `amd64` and `i386`). For packages with this property, `dpkg` shows the architecture along with the package name.

`bind9-hosts` isn’t marked as such, therefore it isn’t co-installable and can only ever be present for one architecture.